# How to check if email exists in laravel Login

Tags: laravel

I want to check if the log in details i.e the email is in the database and echo error like "Email Does Not Exists" in the front-end.

```
$this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Above is my current validation.

How do i check if the email exists before logging them in.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',  // users is table name,email is column 
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
```

in blade you can do as follows

```
@error('email')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use custom validation. Here is an example:

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'email' => ['required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                                    $email = User::where('email', $value)->first();
                                    if ($email == null) {
                                        $fail($attribute.' does not exist.');
                                    }
                 },],
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
```